# Rotate the mergeometry object at its center in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am struggling to find the way to rotate the object at its center. At the moment i am able to rotate the scene, but when i do the rotation, the object goes away from the user. I look into the some the already asked questions in the same line on the forum, but couldn't able to get it work. Below is the part of the html/three.js file i am using /attached you will find the complete working example.Any help is greatly appreciated

```
            <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
            <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

            <script>

                    var container, stats;
                    var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
                    var pickingData = [], pickingTexture, pickingScene;
                    var objects = [];
                    var highlightBox;
                    var splitCoord;
                    var avStdProp;

                    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
                    var offset = new THREE.Vector3( 10, 10, 10 );

                    var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.005, 0.005, 0.005 );
                            geom.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

                    init();
                    animate();

                    function init() {

                            container = document.getElementById( "container" );

                            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );

                            camera.position.x=250;
                            camera.position.y=300;
                            camera.position.z=400;

                            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
                            controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
                            controls.zoomSpeed = 4;
                            controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
                            controls.noZoom = false;
                            controls.noPan = false;
                            controls.staticMoving = true;
                            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

                            scene = new THREE.Scene();


                            pickingScene = new THREE.Scene();
                            pickingTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(800, 800);
                            pickingTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
                            pickingTexture.generateMipmaps = false;

                            scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x555555 ) );

                            var light = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1.5 );
                            light.position.set( 0, 500, 2000 );
                            scene.add( light );

                            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry(),
                            pickingGeometry = new THREE.Geometry(),
                            pickingMaterial = new  THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } ),
                            defaultMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

                            function applyVertexColors( g, c ) {

                                    g.faces.forEach( function( f ) {

                                            var n = ( f instanceof THREE.Face3 ) ? 3 : 4;

                                            for( var j = 0; j < n; j ++ ) {

                                                    f.vertexColors[ j ] = c;

                                            }

                                    } );

                            }

                            var color = new THREE.Color();

                            var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
                            var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

                            var coord="219_163_189;130_173_179;161_113_231;92_103_176;169_193_180;161_165_187;262_163_166;198_143_155;161_189_155;125_121_107";
                            splitCoord=coord.split(";");
                            var coordColr="0_255_255;255_255_0;0_0_255;0_255_0;255_255_0;0_255_0;0_0_255;0_255_255;255_255_0;210_210_45";
                            var splitCoordColor=coordColr.split(";");
                            var avgStd="1_0;3_0;0_0;2_0;3_0;2_0;0_0;1_0;3_0;3_0.35";
                            avStdProp=avgStd.split(";");

                            for ( var i = 0; i < splitCoord.length; i++ ) {

                                    var position = new THREE.Vector3();
                                    var xyz=splitCoord[i].split("_");
                                    var col=splitCoordColor[i].split("_");

                                    position.x = xyz[0];
                                    position.y = xyz[1];
                                    position.z = xyz[2];

                                    var rotation = new THREE.Euler();
                                    rotation.x = 0
                                    rotation.y = 0;
                                    rotation.z = 0;

                                    var scale = new THREE.Vector3();
                                    scale.x = 200 + 100;
                                    scale.y = 200 + 100;
                                    scale.z = 200 + 100;

                                    quaternion.setFromEuler( rotation, false );
                                    matrix.compose( position, quaternion, scale );

                                     // give the geom's vertices a random color, to be displayed

                                    col[0]=col[0]/255;
                                    col[1]=col[1]/255;
                                    col[2]=col[2]/255;

                                    applyVertexColors(geom, color.setRGB(col[0], col[1], col[2]));

                                    geometry.merge( geom, matrix );

                                    // give the geom's vertices a color corresponding to the "id"

                                    applyVertexColors( geom, color.setHex( i ) );

                                    pickingGeometry.merge( geom, matrix );

                                    pickingData[ i ] = {

                                            position: position,
                                            rotation: rotation,
                                            scale: scale

                                    };

                            }

                            var drawnObject = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, defaultMaterial );
                            scene.add( drawnObject );

                            pickingScene.add( new THREE.Mesh( pickingGeometry, pickingMaterial ) );

                            highlightBox = new THREE.Mesh(
                                    new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.009, 0.009, 0.009 ),
                                    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff }
                            ) );
                            scene.add( highlightBox );


                            //renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
                            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                            renderer.setSize(800,800);
                            renderer.sortObjects = false;

                             container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                            renderer.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove );

                    }

                    //

                    function onMouseMove( e ) {

                            mouse.x = e.clientX;
                            mouse.y = e.clientY;

                    }

                    function pick() {
                    //render the picking scene off-screen
                    renderer.render( pickingScene, camera, pickingTexture );

                    //create buffer for reading single pixel
                    var pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array( 4 );

                    //read the pixel under the mouse from the texture
                    renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(pickingTexture, mouse.x+window.pageXOffset, pickingTexture.height - (mouse.y+window.pageYOffset), 1, 1, pixelBuffer);

                    //interpret the pixel as an ID
                    var id = ( pixelBuffer[0] << 16 ) | ( pixelBuffer[1] << 8 ) | ( pixelBuffer[2]);
                    var data = pickingData[ id ];

                    if (data) {

                    //move our highlightBox so that it surrounds the picked object
                    if (data.position && data.rotation && data.scale && controls.enabled){

                     highlightBox.position.copy( data.position );
                     highlightBox.rotation.copy( data.rotation );
                     highlightBox.scale.copy( data.scale ).add( offset );
                     highlightBox.visible = true;
                     }
                     }

                     else {
                                    highlightBox.visible = false;
                            }
                     }

                    function animate() {

                            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                            render();
                            //stats.update();

                    }

                     function render() {
                            controls.update();
                            pick();
                            renderer.render(scene, camera);
                    }
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your objects geometry to center, so the center of the mesh will then be at position (0,0,0) and it wont "move away" while rotating.

Do it like this:

```
geometry.center();
var drawnObject = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, defaultMaterial );
scene.add( drawnObject );
```

**Update**

Because you want to use picking in an unusual way by saving your geometrys coordinates into an array, centering the geometry doesnt help you. Your question was "Rotate the mergeometry object at its center", but it seems like you want to rotate the camera around your geometrys center.

Calculate the bounding sphere of your geometry and set the controls target to its position:

```
drawnObject.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
controls.target = drawnObject.geometry.boundingSphere.center;
```

Comment: Hi Falk, thanks for your solution. Indeed it does work now. But additionally its also created one small problem. If you noticed in my code, there is  this highlight box is there. Purpose of the box is to highlight the point under the mouse pointer. This time the highlight box appear at wrong position than actual mouse pointer. Any idea?

Comment: Picking is not included in your example, so i dont know how you are doing it and cant test it. Have you tried centering the picking geometry also?

Comment: Hi Falk, I tried to center the picking geometry as well, but didn't work. I have updated the example with the pick function i am using. Actually when i center the picking geometry, it indeed pick the right point, but the highlight box appears somewhere else.

Comment: I updated my answer with another solution, rotating around the cubes and picking is working now.

Comment: Hi Falk, Thanks a lot, your solution just work perfect. You save my time buddy. Thanks